# How can I change the style in mat-toolbar-row?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I'd like to make some changes to the code below... Unfortunately it does not work :( Can you please tell me what I need to add to my code.

```
// Standard style from Angular Material
.mat-toolbar-row, .mat-toolbar-single-row {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 16px;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```
// My Code
/deep/ .mat-toolbar-row, .mat-toolbar-single-row {
padding: 0 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: What version of Material are you using. At some point (a long time ago), material team decided to use `encapsulation: none` for all of their components. So your code should work without any problems (and with no need for `/deep/`). If it's an old version, try putting your code in styles.css  to make it global.

Comment: I use Angular Material 8.2.1 and the code is style.css globally defined... Nevertheless it does not work

Comment: I've just copied and pasted your css [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubdzp1?file=src/app/toolbar-overview-example.css) and it worked out of the box.... both with the component css and with styles.css.

Comment: Funny, I just retested it and it works. I don't understand anything now hahaha Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

The `/deep/` selector is depreciated.

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

I suggest you just add a class to your toolbar:

```
<mat-toolbar class="custom-toolbar">With Padding</mat-toolbar>
```

and then set the css for that class:

```
.custom-toolbar {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

I created a little example for you here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7acrk